# Buscar determinadas datas em campo VARCHAR em SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, algoritmo-de-busca, varchar

Eu tenho a seguinte condição:

```sql
WHERE  sv_users.userDataNascimento LIKE '%95%';
```

E esta condição busca numa data (`11/12/1995`), do tipo `VARCHAR` e não `Timestamp`, um ano terminando com os numerais `95`. Este numeral é resultante de um cálculo que faço no meu código para achar o ano de nascimento do usuário buscado no filtro em um formulário.

Eu chego no ano através deste cálculo:

> idadeDigitada - AnoCorrente = AnoDeNascimento

Daí que monto a consulta. Até aqui tudo bem.

Mas, se eu quiser buscar nesse campo uma data que seja menor que, ou maior que o numeral obtido no cálculo, por exemplo, datas (`VARCHAR`) que terminem com os dois últimos numerais menores que o resultante do cálculo (que no caso é `95`), como faço? O que utilizo?

Comment: É possivel converter esse campo para `date`? com `varchar` vc terá problema para ordenar  datas. Para comparar o ano de uma data `date` use `year()`. ex: `select year(now())`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Tente usar uma data de 4 dígitos

Primeiro, tente armazenar a data num campo de data (`DATE`). Depois, seria melhor calcular anos com 4 dígitos para evitar confusões com pessoas de muita ou pouca idade.

Isso porque pessoas com mais de 100 anos ou menos de 15 (considerando o ano de 2014 como base) não apareceriam corretamente no filtro de maior ou menor.

Por exemplo, se alguém nasceu a partir de **2000** e você usar apenas os dois últimos dígitos, a comparação `anoNascimento < 0` não retornaria nenhuma data.

O mesmo ocorre para pessoas de mais idade. Por exemplo, se alguém nasceu em **1990*, uma comparação por `anoNascimento < 90` não incluiria os anos 2000 em diante.

Isso poderia ser parcialmente contornado com alguma lógica adicional, considerando um ano base e supondo que nenhuma das datas de nascimento será muito antiga. Porém, fuja dessas gambiarras.

Enfim, usando anos de 4 dígitos a query ficaria mais simples e poderíamos usar a função [`YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) como no exemplo abaixo:

```sql
WHERE YEAR(sv_users.userDataNascimento) > 1995;
```

E neste outro:

```sql
WHERE YEAR(sv_users.userDataNascimento) < 1995;
```

### Solução para comparação com dois dígitos

Por outro lado, se quiser mesmo verificar o ano num campo `VARCHAR`, considerando o formato `dd/mm/aaaa` ou `dd/mm/aa`, uma opção seria a função [`RIGHT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) e [converter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) o resultado para número:

```sql
WHERE CONVERT(RIGHT(sv_users.userDataNascimento, 2), SIGNED) > 95;
```

Ou

```sql
WHERE CONVERT(RIGHT(sv_users.userDataNascimento, 2), SIGNED) < 95;
```

Exemplo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7643bb/8).

Comment: Fiz alguns ajustes na resposta, pois o último exemplo não estava funcional.

Comment: Esqueceu do caso de alguém que por exemplo nasceu em 2002 no right com 2 casas, não? (talvez o problema ja esteja na pergunta)

Comment: @Bacco Bem, é uma ótima ideia explicitar isso. Quando eu afirmei que "seria melhor calcular anos com 4 dígitos", não quis citar exemplos específicos nem cobrir todos os casos. Mas agora que você falou, vi que realmente vale a pena mencionar.

Comment: Se quiser pode somar um fator (epoch) nos dois lados e usar módulo pra corrigir isso,  mas vai ficando complexo. Talvez seja o caso de um comentário mesmo. O que eu concordo é que o varchar dá mais dor de cabeça do que qq coisa.

Comment: @Bacco Concordo. Adicionei alguns comentários na resposta. Cada vez que penso nessa solução usando duas casas, parece que vejo um problema pior.

Answer (score 8):

Se não for possivel alterar o tipo da coluna de `varchar` para `date`, [str_to_date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) pode contornar essa situação.

```sql
SELECT str_to_date(userDataNascimento, "%d/%m/%Y") FROM tabela
WHERE year(str_to_date(userDataNascimento, "%d/%m/%Y")) < 1995
```

Exemplo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3e49/2)

Answer (score 5):

Use a função [date_format()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) do MySQL, em que ficaria algo do tipo:

```sql
SELECT id
FROM sua_tabela
WHERE 95 > DATE_FORMAT(sv_users.userDataNascimento, '%y');
```

Ali na chamada, se quiser a data atual, coloque um `NOW()` ou `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

O segundo parâmetro é o formato que quer que seja retornado, `%y` é o ano com dois dígitos, `%Y` é o ano com 4 dígitos.

Olhe o link da documentação para maior explicação.