# Como obter mês e ano de uma data?

Tags: mysql

Como obtenho o mês e o ano de uma data `varchar` no `MySQL`?

Exemplo:

```
31/01/2013
31/02/2013
01/03/2013
01/01/2014
```

Quero somente as datas `01/2013` no caso de `31/01/2013`

Comment: Sua data é um varchar?

Comment: Vai compara com outro varchar

Comment: [Buscar determinadas datas em campo VARCHAR em SQL MySQL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2055/91)

Comment: Não seria somente você converter seu varchar para date pegando somente a MM/yyyy e fazer o where?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se teu campo de data for do tipo `varchar`, precisas convertê-lo antes para o formato `date`  utilizando a função [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date), depois podes usar as funções [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) e [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) :

Combinando as funções, seria algo como:

```
SELECT YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(data, "%d/%m/%Y")) FROM tabela;

SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(data, "%d/%m/%Y")) FROM tabela;
```

Exemplo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8d70fd/4)

Comment: Não entendi o voto negativo, visto que respondi de forma objetiva o problema da questão.

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente

Answer (score 1):

Se as datas estiverem em campos do tipo `date` ou `datetime`,  poderá usar `YEAR` e `MONTH`:

```
SELECT * FROM SUA_TABELA where year(CAMPODATA) = 2013 and month(CAMPODATA) = 1;
```

Comment: O que faz o `Year` e o que faz o `Month`?  Como eles funcionam? Porque `Month(CAMPODATA) = 1`? Se der uma melhorada nos detalhes, eu darei +1 :D

Comment: -1 Pois ele citou que o formato do campo, apesar de ser incorreto, é `varchar`, tua query não retornaria o esperado.

Comment: @MarcelodeAndrade , minha resposta visou buscar orientar na melhor forma, e não necessariamente responder a questão apenas para ganhar pontos. Afinal, porque motivo alguém irá usar uma data em formato varchar e perder todos os recursos do formato date?

Comment: A pergunta fala sobre como selecionar o mês e o ano, ou seja, isolá-los  de uma data completa. Sua resposta não retorna o perguntado.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters month(CAMPODATA) retorna um inteiro correspondente ao mês da data (exemplo: janeiro = 1, dezembro = 12, etc.), year(campodata) retorna o inteiro correspondente ao ano da data, ex: (2013 para o ano de 2013, etc), logo, year(campodata) = 2013 traz todas as datas que possuem o ano 2013 e em seguida, filtra pelo mês, onde month(campodata) = 1, traz tudo que for do mês de janeiro.

Answer (score 1):

Seria isso?

```
select 
    str_to_date('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y') as txtData,
    year(str_to_date('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y')),    
    month(str_to_date('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y'))    
from pedidos    
where   
    year(str_to_date('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y')) = 2011
    and  month(str_to_date('12/31/2011', '%m/%d/%Y'))   = 12
```